# Google Cloud Vision fails at batch annotate images. Getting Netty Shaded ClosedChannelException error

Tags: java, netty, google-cloud-vision

I'm using the Java Google Vision API to run through a batch of images to find the Web properties and that's been working fine the last couple months.I'm now getting a channel closed and ClosedChannelException error on the request. I created a new project with just the [Google provided example](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) to test and I run into the same issue.

I updated my Maven dependency version to the most current and still get the issue on the original application and the new test project.

It errors on the request here:

```
BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = vision.batchAnnotateImages(requests);
```

This is the error message I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnknownException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN: channel closed
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:47)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:95)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:61)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1123)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:435)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:900)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:811)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:675)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:492)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:467)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:41)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:684)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:41)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:391)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:475)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:63)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:557)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$600(ClientCallImpl.java:478)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:590)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN: channel closed
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:526)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.Utils.statusFromThrowable(Utils.java:161)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientTransport$5.operationComplete(NettyClientTransport.java:254)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientTransport$5.operationComplete(NettyClientTransport.java:248)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:481)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:420)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure(DefaultPromise.java:113)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.setFailure(DefaultChannelPromise.java:87)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$AbstractBufferingHandler.fail(ProtocolNegotiators.java:558)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$BufferUntilTlsNegotiatedHandler.userEventTriggered(ProtocolNegotiators.java:652)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:329)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:315)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:307)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslUtils.notifyHandshakeFailure(SslUtils.java:317)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.notifyHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1533)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1518)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelInactive(SslHandler.java:1004)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1354)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:917)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:822)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelInactive(...)(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest filing a bug within the Google's [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187174&template=0) so their Vision API engineering team could do a deep research about this matter.